# Sitecore Solr Search result items matching count

Tags: solr, sitecore

I am using Sitecore Solr search for searching using a keyword string, Is there a way to know the number of matches for each of the returned result items?.

The following is the code I am using:

```cs
using (var context = Index.CreateSearchContext())
{
     List<Item> ResultList = new List<Item>();

     var contentPredicate = PredicateBuilder.True<customSearchResultItem>();
     contentPredicate = contentPredicate.And(p => p.Content.Contains(SearchKey));
     contentPredicate = contentPredicate.And(p => p.Name != "__Standard Values");

     var languagePredicate = PredicateBuilder.True<customSearchResultItem>();
     languagePredicate = languagePredicate.And(p => p.Language == Context.Language.Name);

     var CombinPredicates = PredicateBuilder.True<customSearchResultItem>();
     CombinPredicates = CombinPredicates.And(languagePredicate);
     CombinPredicates = CombinPredicates.And(contentPredicate);

     // execute the search
     IQueryable<customSearchResultItem> query = context.GetQueryable<customSearchResultItem>().Where(CombinPredicates);
     var hits = query.GetResults().Hits;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by adding boosting values to each predicate then the for each result item I got the score and divide it by .59 which in my case the maximum value that occurs when all predicates staesfied; The code in details can be found on the following blog post:

http://sitecoreinfo.blogspot.com/2015/10/sitecore-solr-search-result-items.html

Answer (score 1):

From what I know, you can not get the number of matches for every result item based on the keyword used for search. What you can get, is a **score** value from Solr.

```cs
var hits = query.GetResults().Hits;
foreach (var hit in hits)
{
    var score = hit.Score;
}
```

This is the value for the whole query, so it includes all predicates like `language`, `not Standard Values` and `keywords` in your case.

Remember, that this value can be different if you use Solr and if you use Lucene - this is dependent on the internal calculations.

Comment: I tried this before and the score value will be the same for all the result items if the keyword predicate match, I need something like incrementing the score value for each match found on the current item?.